# I am using already configured hadoop which is given by my friend, so how to get name of the namenode?

Tags: hadoop

I am using already configured Hadoop which was given by my friend. Here is the content of `hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.block.size</name>
        <value>67108864</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

How to get the name of the NameNode?

Answer (score 1):

You have to see the below parameter in core-site.xml

```
fs.default.name (or) fs.defaultFS
```

which is set in property tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at core-site.xml and the parameter is fs.defaultFS.